# When are supremum/infimum of sets values not contained in this set?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I am a bit unsure about how the supremum/infimum of a set is obtained, in particular in the following simple toy example.

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the identity function, i.e. $f(x)=x$ for all $x$.

Now I am interested in $a:=\inf\{x \colon f(x) > 0 \}$ and $b:=\inf\{x > 0 \colon f(x) > 0\}$.

I wonder whether $a=b$ and whether $a$ or $b$ are equal to 0.

We had in a lecture about probability theory the following examples:

In one example we considered for the distribution function $F$ and a $x \in [0,1]$ the quantity

$\sup\{y \in \mathbb{R} \colon F(y) < x\}$.

The picture drawn corresponding to this example suggests that when the function is continuous at the point $y^*$ such that $F(y^*)=x$ and $y^*$ is the smallest value mapped to $x$, then the supremum is $y^*$, even though $y^*$ does not satisfy the property that $F(y^*) < x$.

In some other example we had $\sup A_n = \emptyset$ with $A_n:=(0,1/n)$.

Now I wonder why it is not the case that $\sup A_n = 0$, as in the above example we also picked a number not part of the set, and here $0$ is not part of the set as well, but would satisfy the other property of being $<1/n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Since your $f$ is the identity function $f(x)=x$, you must have $a=b$. The infimum is defined on a set, so you can see in the case of $a$ the set in question is $(0,\infty)$ and in the case of $b$ the set is $(0,\infty)$. Since these are  the same, the infima must be the same.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is what I expected. Is it 0 now? If not, what is it then?
And if it is 0, why is $\sup A_n = \emptyset$ and not $\sup A_n = 0$? Maybe I am also confusing things, because in the first example with the identity function we take the infimum over a set, and in the second example with the $A_n$ we take the supremum over a sequence of sets. So maybe this is the point I do not understand..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $\emptyset$, the supremum is a real number. You must have $\sup (0, {1 \over n}) = {1 \over n}$, since ${1 \over n}$ is an upper bound, and for all $\epsilon >0$ there are points $x$ in the set that satisfy $x > {1 \over n} - \epsilon$.

Comment: I am sorry for the misleading notation. So I want to consider $\sup_n A_n$, so $n$ is not fixed here. And we have the convention that $\sup \emptyset = \emptyset$, I guess, but I am not sure, though.

Comment: The notation $\sup_n A_n$ doesn't really make sense here (sometimes you see things like $\sup_n x_n$ where $x_n$ are real numbers, but $A_n$ is a set).

Comment: Oh, I see. I am sorry again. I am so confused, wherefore I mix up several things. So actually we are considering $\limsup_n A_n$. But still I do not get why this should be undefined and not 0, when comparing to the example with the distribution function..

Comment: There is a notion of $\limsup$ for sets, but I don't think this is what you are dealing with yet. If you wrote $\lim_n \sup A_n$ (see the difference?) that would make sense and would be $\lim_n {1 \over n} = 0$.

Comment: Yes, I think we are dealing with limsup for sets, because this occurs in the first Lemma of Borel Cantelli. As far as I can understand, the limsup of a set is some value that is in infinitely many of these sets. So intuitively, I can understand that there is no value in infinitely many sets, as the only possibility being $<1/n$ for infinitely many $n$ would be 0, but 0 is excluded. 
But then related to the question with the distribution function: Not being contained in the set does not prevent a value from being the infimum of a set..

Comment: You are asking a few questions here. The $\operatorname{Lim}\sup$ of a countable collection of sets is $\cap_n \cup_{k \ge n} A_k$. In your case you can see that $ \cup_{k \ge n} A_k = (0, {1 \over n})$ and hence $\cap_n (0,{1 \over n}) = \emptyset$. However, I would encourage you not to mix up the two concepts in a question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess I now understand the concept of limsup of sets a little bit better now. Can you help me with the question whether $a=b=0$ or $a,b$ are undefined? When $a=b=0$, can you tell me how this does relate to the answer I got to this question? And if they are not defined, can you maybe help me what the issue with this distribution function is? Because I am quite sure that this all is the same concept, namely sup/inf over a set..

Comment: See my first comment about $a,b$.

Comment: I reread it, but you only state that they must be the same, but I cannot see whether they must be the same *and* 0.

Comment: What is  $\inf (0,\infty)$?

Comment: I would say it is 0, but by now I wouldn't bet on that. I am really really confused. :-)

But I guess I see the point now that was confusing me: Mixing the two concepts, which I never should do, as you suggested. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The answer is $0$ because (i) $0$ is a lower bound, and (ii) for every $\epsilon>0$ there is some element $x \in (0,\infty)$ such that $x > 0 +\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example; On the real line open sets do not contain thier supremum.

If a set is open then you can always find smaller numbers then a given number you might claim being your sup and still stay outside the set. In a closed set the boundary possess a property that makes this impossible since any ball around a point on the boundary intersect both the set and the complement.

Comment: When this is the case, can you explain to me why in the above example with the distribution function the supremum would be $y^*$ and not undefined?

Comment: Isnt this the least number being an upper found for your set $\{ y \in R ; F(y) < x \}$ i.e the sup of this set. Also this is an open set.

Comment: I am not completely sure what you want to tell me: So you mean that $y^*$ would *not* be the supremum, but the smallest value being an upper bound on this set, which is *not* the same as the supremum?

I am not sure whether there are several definitions of sup then, but I am quite sure that we just use $y^*$ as the supremum value..

Comment: I did not say y* is not sup, it is the sup. "Isnt this" in my other comment ;this = y*. Sorry for being sloppy

Comment: Oh, I misread your statement. you meant that it is not contained and I read that it does not exist.. I am sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If $F$ is a (cumulative) distribution function, we have $\lim_{x \downarrow \infty} F(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \uparrow \infty} F(x) = 1$, and $F$ is non decreasing and continuous from the right.

It follows that the set $S = \{y | F(y) < x \}$ must either (1) be empty, (2) be the real line or (3) have the
form $(-\infty,t)$ for some $t$ (in which case we have $\sup S = t$).

In Case (3), $S$ cannot include $t$ since $F$ is right continuous. We must have $F(t) \ge x$.

If $F$ is continuous then in Case (3) we must have $F(t) = x$. Furthermore,
if $F(s) = x$ for some $s < t$, we must have $F(y) = x$ for $y \in [s,t]$ and
so $[s,t] \cap S = \emptyset$ which contradicts $S$ having the form
$(0,t)$. Hence, when $F$ is continuous, we see that
$\sup S =t= \inf \{ s | F(s) = x \}$, and we must have
$F(t) = x$ and $F(s) < x$ for $s <t$.

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Thank you!!